# Mappings in RestController not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I have a RestController that defines a default path and some endpoints like this:

```
@RestController
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
@RequestMapping(path = "/somePath", produces = "application/hal+json")
public class SomeRestController {

  @GetMapping (path = "/otherPath")
  public String someEndpoint(){
  return "hello";
  }

    ...other endpoints...
}
```

I get a 404 for the mapped endpoints. However, if I delete the default RequestMapping the endpoints suddenly get picked up! I also tried RequestMapping ( path =..., method=RequestMethod.GET) for the endpoints, but same result...

If I delete the @GetMapping from one endpoint, the default path is mapped successfully.

What is going on here? Why do the endpoints don't get mapped if I have the default RequestMapping?

Comment: How you call your controller?

Comment: A GET for localhost:8080/otherPath

This works, if I remove the default RequestMapping (/somePath)

Comment: default RequestMapping path should be included in URL of every Apis in this controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concat both pathes:

```
localhost:8080/somePath/otherPath
```

because the mapping on top of the class is for all methods in this controller, and than the method specific path will be added